# Abstraction layer over the file system and jar/zip in Java

Tags: java, file, jar

Is there a Java library, which provides an *abstraction layer* over the file system and jar/zip. I checked [apache common vfs](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html) but it does not support such operations as listing directory content and file rename for Jar/Zip.

Suppose there is some code, which uses `java.io.File` and its friends to access files in the file system, and I need to make it work if these files are in Jar/Zip. I would like to find an API, which is very similar to `java.io.File`, to make the code refactoring easier.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used it yet, but are you looking for the [Zip File System Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) introduced in Java 7?

Answer (score 0):

Zip File System Provider doesn't work as the abstraction layer exactly because of java.io.File:

```
public class ZipPath implements Path {

@Override
public final File toFile() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

The closest API I could find is TrueZIP/TrueVFS by Christian Schlichtherle https://truevfs.java.net/ but it has its own issues.