# lightweight Java interface/library for abstracting read-only source tree?

Tags: java, filesystems

I need to provide an abstraction layer for a read-only source tree in Java, that includes the ability to iterate over files and subdirectories, and read contents of files. The purpose is so that I can provide a source tree to an application, whether it's a physical source tree on disk, or the contents of a .zip file, or the subcontents of a .zip file under a subdirectory, or a virtual set of files from a database.

Is there any lightweight interface / library that can help provide this abstraction layer?

I found these related questions:

- [Abstraction layer over the file system and jar/zip in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249838/abstraction-layer-over-the-file-system-and-jar-zip-in-java)
- [Java library for abstracting I/O when reading resources from folders/jar files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847560/java-library-for-abstracting-i-o-when-reading-resources-from-folders-jar-files)

and they both refer to the [`FileSystem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) API. This is interesting but it includes lots of features for modification and notification that aren't relevant and that I would have to implement to meet the API behavior.